# Joining two most recent events from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, medical

I'm trying to build a report in SQL that shows when a patient last received a particular lab service and the facility at which they've received that service.  Unfortunately, the lab procedure and facility are in different tables.  Here is what I have now (apologies in advance for my weird aliasing, it makes better since with the actual table names):

```
;with temp as (Select distinct flow.pid, flow.labdate as obsdate, flow.labvalue as obsvalue
            From labstable as flow 
            Where flow.name = 'lab name' 
        )
Select distinct p.patientid, MAX(temp.obsdate) [Last Reading], COUNT(temp.obsdate) [Number of Readings], 
Case 
When count(temp.obsdate) > 2 then 'Active'Else 'Inactive' End [Status], facility.NAME [Facility]

From Patientrecord as p 
Join temp on temp.pid = p.PId
Join (Select loc.name, MAX(a.apptstart)[Last appt], a.patientid
    From Appointmentstable as a 
    Join Facility as loc on loc.facilityid = a.FacilityId
    Where a.ApptStart = (Select MAX(appointments.apptstart) from Appointments where appointments.patinetId = a.patientid)
    Group by loc.NAME, a.patientId
    ) facility on facility.patientId = p.PatientId

Group by p.PatientId, facility.NAME
Having MAX(temp.obsdate) between DATEADD(yyyy, -1, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
Order by [Last Reading] asc
```

My problem with this is that if the patient has been to more than one facility within the time frame, the subquery is selecting each facility into the join, inflating the results by apprx 4000.  I need to find a way to select ONLY the VERY MOST RECENT facility from the appointments list, then join it back to the lab.  Labs do not have a visitID (that would make too much sense).  I'm fairly confident that I'm missing something in either my subquery select or the corresponding join, but after four days I think I need professional help.

Suggestions are much appreciated and please let me know where I can clarify.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using `row_number` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: Update: There was a filtering error on the database, query is now returning one facility per user.  Wasn't sure if it was appropriate to update or delete, but this query does work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your subquery with alias "facility" to something like this:

```
...
join (
select patientid, loc_name, last_appt
from (
    select patientid, loc_name=loc.name, last_appt=apptstart, 
        seqnum=row_number() over (partition by patientid order by apptstart desc)
    from AppointmentsTable a
    inner join Facility loc on loc.facilityid = a.facilityid
) x
where seqnum = 1
) facility
on ...
...
```

The key difference is the use of the row_number() windowing function. The "partition by" and "order by" clauses guarantee you'll get one set of row numbers per patient and the row with the most recent date will be assigned row number 1. The filter of "seqnum = 1" makes sure you get *only the one row you want* for each patient.

Comment: I recommend also running just that subquery by itself to learn more about how the row_number() function works before integrating it into the larger query. Assuming you're using SQL Server 2008 or later, you should find windowing functions very powerful and very handy.

Comment: Thanks, I think is is exactly what I was looking for.  I did get it to run, but I'm going to hit this problem a few times over the next few months, so I am glad to know this solution.